# Не работает привязка в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Width="187" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}" Canvas.Left="167" Canvas.Top="80" x:Name="DataGrid">
     <DataGrid.DataContext>
          <local:TestViewModel />
     </DataGrid.DataContext>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="test" Width="*">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal">
                           <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding LinesWeight}" SelectedItem="{Binding LineWeight,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SetWeightCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBox>
                       </StackPanel>
                  </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

C#: TestViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Layers { get; set; }
public TestViewModel()
{
    Layers=new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    Layers.Add(new ItemViewModel());
}
```

C#: ItemViewModel

```
public ItemViewModel()
{
    LinesWeight = new[] { 0,1,2,3,4.5};
    SetWeightCommand=new RelayCommand(OnSet);
}

void OnSet()
{
    MessageBox.Show(LineWeight+"");
}

public double[] LinesWeight { get; set; }

public RelayCommand SetWeightCommand { get; set; }

double _lineWeight;
public double LineWeight
{
    get {return _lineWeight; }
    set
    {
        _lineWeight = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => LineWeight);
    }
}
```

Планируемый результат: при переключении выводится `MessageBox` с текущим выбранным в `ComboBox` значением, привязанным на `LineWeight`. Что имею: при переключении выводится не текущее выбранное значение, а то что было в начале, в данном примере 0. Если установить `LineWeight` в коде в другое значение, например 2, то будет каждый раз выводится 2, и т.д. 
  То есть, не работает привязка выбранного значения. Как это исправить? Предположительно, проблема в самом `DataGrid`, но с чем именно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут поможет `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`:

```
 SelectedItem="{Binding LineWeight, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

**UPD**: обнаружилась одна особенность, если `ComboBox` расположить вне `DataTemplate`, то  `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` не нужен. Значение обновляется до того как произойдет событие `SelectionChanged` что по сути и правильно.